# Was there an announcement for the 3rd season of Vampire Knight anime?

Tags: vampire-knight

I watched 2 seasons of *Vampire Knight* about 2 years ago. As I know, the manga is still continuing.

Was there an announcement for the 3rd season?

Comment: The OP was under the impression that this manga is ongoing. The answer can resolve that no unannounced future events known only to creators will occur, as the manga ended 2 yrs ago, the anime 7 yrs ago, & [no further anime was announced during the manga's run](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/press-release/2014-09-25/viz-media-announces-the-finale-of-matsuri-hino-series-vampire-knight/.79185). All of the answer is about past releases & announcements. This is of use on SE, as a Google search for "Vampire Knight season 3" turns up erroneous claims that a 3rd season was announced, which it wasn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Vampire Knight* manga by Hino Matsuri ended its run in *LaLa* manga magazine on [May 24th, 2013](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vampire_Knight) with [chapter 93](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Vampire_Knight_chapters#Chapters_not_yet_collected_in_tank.C5.8Dbon). However, [2 side-story chapters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Vampire_Knight_chapters#Chapters_not_yet_collected_in_tank.C5.8Dbon) were not published within the *tankoubon* graphic novels. Two light novels authored by Hino Matsuri were published in 2008: *Vampire Knight: Ice Blue no Tsumi* and *Vampire Knight: Noir no Wana*.

The second season of the anime, *Vampire Knight Guilty*, ended its run on [December 29th, 2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Vampire_Knight_episodes) (4 1/2 years earlier than the manga ended). No further TV anime or other anime adaption was announced before the manga's final chapter.